# EasyAdmin automatically set up a user_id when adding a new entry to an entity

Tags: php, symfony, backend, easyadmin

I'm using easyadmin with my online learning website project for school.
Teachers can add formations, sections which are attached to formations, and lessons which belong to sections. I set up three cruds for each, and queries so the logged in user can only see content they created.

The issue is that when adding a new entry, easyadmin doesn't set up the logged in user_id in the database, and I get the following error:
An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'user_id' cannot be null

I get where it's coming from, you can't add an entry to the database without the user_id since it's not nullable, but I can't seem to find where I can set up easyadmin so it always passes the user_id when adding a new entry. Can you edit the add action somewhere?

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in the [docs](https://symfony.com/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/current/crud.html#creating-persisting-and-deleting-entities) example code below, you need to manually set the user on your entity (currently logged-in user is returned by `$this->getUser()`) in your `AbstractCrudController::createEntity` method.

```php
//    src: https://symfony.com/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/current/crud.html#creating-persisting-and-deleting-entities
// copied: 2022-04-13

namespace App\Controller\Admin;

use App\Entity\Product;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\AbstractCrudController;

class ProductCrudController extends AbstractCrudController
{
    public static function getEntityFqcn(): string
    {
        return Product::class;
    }

    public function createEntity(string $entityFqcn)
    {
        $product = new Product();
        $product->createdBy($this->getUser());

        return $product;
    }

    // ...
}
```